# How to read a text file during a Windows Forms application installation

Tags: c#, winforms

This seem a very odd question but I'd like to know if this is possible. I'm dealing with a Japanese boss that requested a custom launching program, which I accomplished using Windows Forms. From that launcher you can launch 3 installed casino programs.

The bad news is, there is a certain casino application which path is not installed in Program Files folder. It is installed on user's Appdata folder instead.

What I did is, when you click the launch button of that casino

```
private void AlienLaunchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Process p = Process.Start(@"%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Programs\Alien Casino\1.2.135\Alien Casino.exe");
}
```

But I get an unhandled exception error

[image]

I discussed it that if it will be used on various computers, the file path differs.

So he came up with a crazy idea to put a text file having the paths written inside it and when you fire up the installation setup of the custom Launcher, it should get the paths contained on that text file.

Is this even possible? If not what is the best solution to this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
Process p = Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)+@"\AppData\Local\Programs\Alien Casino\1.2.135\Alien Casino.exe");
```

[image]

BTW if you're not using fw4+ , you can use this instead :

`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")`

After your edit : see the exception. it says it can't find the file.

Comment: Tried it but I get the error "Environment.SpecialFolder' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: I tried ```Process p = Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Local\Programs\Alien Casino\1.2.135\Alien Casino.exe");``` instead but i still get an Unhandled exception error.

Comment: Did you add `UserProfile` ? Copy the EXACT line.What's the exception ?

Comment: Yes. The error is ```'Environment.SpecialFolder' does not contain a definition for 'UserProfile'```.

Comment: Why not use `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` directly?

Comment: See for yourself  , I've added an image. please paste the code you use

Comment: For UserProfile this is what it looks like. https://postimg.cc/p97zD1SW

Comment: @leipz You aren't using fw4+ ? If no - Try this instead `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")`

Comment: Thank you @NineBerry the program launched with ```Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData```. I omitted ```AppData\Local``` file path. So the final code is ```Process p = Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Programs\Alien Casino\1.2.135\Alien Casino.exe");```

Comment: @RoyiNamir Still using fw3.5 for the meantime. ```System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")``` worked too. Thank you Sir!